# Looking for the source of a quotation about how to draw beautifully

Tags: quote-source

I vaguely remember a quotation that I might have read in a book many years ago, but can't remember exactly, what or where that was. Various search engines have been of little help, so far. It goes something like this:

> "If you want to learn how to draw beautifully, first become beautiful – then draw naturally!"

This might have had something to do with Asian or Zen philosophy, hinting more at "inner" beauty or enlightenment, rather than "outer" beauty, but I'm not sure.

Does anybody happen to know the source or the correct wording?